# I'd like to cast a ray to an imaginary plane engendered by x axis and z axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have my editor camera and I'd like to spawn objects where it is looking, as well as it is done by unity when primitives are Instantiated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you provide code snippets? Also, just to be clear, are you looking at creating objects in Editor Mode, or in Play Mode?

Comment: @ExaltedBagel I didn't tried anything so far. Still collecting informations about how to do it.
What I'm working on is a robot Importer from URDF files, everything works fine but i need to instantiate my robot somewhere and i'd like to instantiate it in front of Editor's camera

Comment: Edit : I may have found something.
I'll try using : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint.html
with 'Camera.current'.

Comment: Please be more specific on what exactly you try to achieve .. e.g. spawn in front of exactly which camera? And "in front" how far away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the title of your questions you want to raycast from the scene view camera against the global XZ axis which passes through the world origin and place an object at the hit position.

To find the "editor" or better said the SceneView camera you can use [`SceneView.camera`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneView-camera.html).

```
var camera = SceneView.camera;
```

Then for creating a ray from it use either [`Camera.ScreenPointToRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html) e.g. if you want to take the mouse position into account

```
var ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
```

or simply the cameras [`Transform.forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html) vector

```
var ray = new Ray(camera.transform.position, camera.transform.forward);
```

Or alternatively if you are calling this from within [`Editor.OnSceneGUI`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.OnSceneGUI.html) you could also use [`HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay.html)

```
var ray = HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay(Event.current.mousePosition);
```

Then for raycasting against the global XZ plane you can use a mathematical [`Plane`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.html)

```
// Creates a XZ plane going through world origin
var plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
```

Then you can raycast against it using [`Plane.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.Raycast.html)

```
if(plane.Raycast(ray, out var distance)
{
    var hitPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);

    // Spawn your object and set its position to hitPoint
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem but in the end I don't need to do that.

To answer to your questions :

> Please be more specific on what exactly you try to achieve .. e.g. spawn in front of   > exactly which camera? And "in front" how far away?

I needed to instantiate my robot Prefab at the intersection of the XZ plane and the Raycast shot from the editor's view camera no matter how far it is.

And yeah I managed to make it work as Hugo saidin his previous answer.